# didFinishLaunching post notification don't work

Tags: ios, notifications

I post a notification at the app launch time, and add observer in ViewController.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(show) name:@"TestNotification" object:nil];
```

but the selector show don't be invoked. i am confused about this, so please give me some help, thank you!

Comment: add code for how to invoked method  you are

Comment: add postNotificationWithName in didfinishLaunchingWithOption

Comment: there not code for invoke. when observer observe the notification, it will auto invoke the selector(at here is show method), right? But under normal condition, for example if i add the postNotification code at the `applicationWillEnterForeground` method, then the show method will be invoked successfully.